# Need somebody to explain a simple question concerning loops

Tags: javascript, function, loops, if-statement

```js
function foo(i) 
  {
  if (i < 0) return; 
  console.log('begin: ' + i); 
  foo(i - 1); 
  console.log('end: ' + i); 
} 
foo(3);
```

this code prints out:

```
begin: 3 
begin: 2 
begin: 1 
begin: 0 
end: 0 
end: 1 
end: 2 
end: 3
```

I understand how the begin results work alright.
I just can't wrap my head around the logic behind the "end: " lines.
Why does it start counting from zero up to 3 again please it isn't making any sense to me.
Somebody please explain the code to me I'm a novice

Comment: Instead of console logs, set a breakpoint in your browser and inspect what's happening.

Comment: Because this is recursive, you aren't really looping. You get to the last item and then start outputting the `end` value as each recursive call starts to exit. Recursive functions will exit the opposite order in which they're called (the stack order).

Comment: Before `foo(3)` can end, it has to execute `foo(2)`. But before `foo(2)` can end, it has to execute `foo(1)`. But before `foo(1)` can end, it has to execute `foo(0)`. `foo(0)` runs, executes `foo(-1)` which does nothing but `return`, and  prints `end: 0`. Now, `foo(1)` can end by logging `end: 1`. Now `foo(2)` can end by logging `end: 2`... you get the idea

Answer (score 0):

Using recursion doesn't actually cause a function to loop, rather, it simply adds the current call to the 'stack' and continues on to the next function. To simplify, you can think of it as almost nesting functions inside each other every time recursion is called. Since you are making the recursive call before logging each time, the current function that is running gets put on pause essentially, and added to the stack until the next function is done running. This will continue until all functions have reached that point of recursion and have called it, then the stack will be emptied in reverse order, finishing each function until the stack is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Function doesn't terminates if it calls other function or itself. When a function calls an other function the execution of current function is paused and it's contents and return address are stored in some stack and the execution of called function is started. When called function finishes it's operation the control is then passed back to the calling function and the execution of calling function is resumed and it's contents are fetched from memory.